# Weird C++ templating issues

Tags: c++, c, gcc

So basically the assignment was we had to create a doubly linked list that's templated generically instead of locked to a single data type.  I've tried compiling both with gcc and msvc and both compilers are giving me roughly the same errors so I'm assuming its just my bad coding and not the quirkyness of one compiler or the other.

Currently, I'm getting errors saying that my classes in `linkList.h` are not a template

> ../linkList.h:34: error: ‘llist’ is not a template type
>   ../linkList.h:143: error: ‘iter’ is not a template type
>   ../josephus.cpp:14: error: ‘llist’ is not a template
>   ../josephus.cpp:14: error: aggregate ‘llist ppl’ has incomplete type
>   and cannot be defined
>  ../josephus.cpp:15: error: ‘iter’ is not a
>   template

**linkList.h**

---

```
template<typename T>
class iter
{
public:
iter()
{
    position = sentin;
    container = sentin->payload;
}

T get() const
{
    assert(position != sentin);
    return position->payload;
}

void next()
{
    position = position->next;
}

void previous()
{
    position = position->prev;
}

bool equals(iter itr) const
{
    return position == itr.position;
}
private:
node *position;
llist *container;
};
```

**josephus.cpp**

---

```
llist<int> ppl;
iter<int> pos;

int start = static_cast<int>(argv[1]) - 1;
int end = static_cast<int>(argv[2]) - 1;
```

Any help in this matter is much appreciated

Comment: As a matter of style, there's nothing wrong with asking for homework help, but please don't say "I don't get it!" and dump all your code on other people. Try to post as little code as possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edited down for clarity, sorry about that

Comment: It's cool - everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: You need a bit more code than that. Not all the types are defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your forward declaration says `llist` is a class:

```
class llist;
```

Then you say it is a template:

```
template<typename T>
class llist;
```

Similarly with `iter`.

I don't know how you could make it compilable easily.  However, you can make `node` and `iter` 'inside' of `llist`.

Comment: Ah crap, well that does make sense now that I see the answer.  Can't believe I made an error like that, thanks.

Comment: by "inside," I believe he means private to the llist class. This is how I would do it.

Comment: Here's a link to a very similar question elsewhere on SO. I found this question (and your correct answer) when researching the other. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590688/class-is-not-a-template-type

Comment: I have simlar error because i use friend like
friend class ComponentNode; and ComponentNode was template ;/

Answer (score 3):

The llist is not a class. So forward declaring it is not usefull.

```
template<typename T> class llist;
```

Trying to make the code compile is relatively simple.
You have just missed the template part of a lot of the types. Search for iter llist and node and make sure they have the appropriate  on the end.

If you look at the STL it is conventinal to typedef some internal types for ease of use. You could follow the same principle.

```
template<typename T>
class llist
{
     typedef iter<T>  Iter;
     typedef node<T>  Node;

      // The rest of the code.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues.

```
class A;
```

is not the way you forward declare a templated class.

If A has a single templated parameter you need to say:

```
template<typename T>
class A;
```

If you say that after you've already said `class A;` you're contradicting yourself. The next issue is simlar, `friend class A;` if A is templated won't work, you need to say `friend class A<T>;` or similar. Finally, `static_cast<int>(argv[1])` will not compile (althought `static_cast<int>(argv[1][0])` would, but is still not want you want). To convert a string to an integer meaningfully, you'll need to use `atoi`, `strtol`, `stringstream` etc.

Comment: Thanks for that heads up on atoi, that was one of the errors I was preparing to work on