# Class 'is not a template type'

Tags: c++, templates

What does this error mean?

```
Generic.h:25: error: 'Generic' is not a template type
```

Here's Generic.

```
template <class T>
class Generic: public QObject, public CFG, public virtual Evaluator {
    Q_OBJECT
    std::string key_;
    std::vector<std::string> layouts_;
    std::vector<std::string> static_widgets_;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<widget_template> > widget_templates_;
    std::map<std::string, Widget *> widgets_;
    int type_;
    LCDWrapper *wrapper_;

    protected:
    LCDText *lcdText_;

    public:
    Generic(Json::Value *config, int type);
    ~Generic();
    void CFGSetup(std::string key);
    void BuildLayouts();
    void StartLayout();
    int GetType() { return type_; }
    //T *GetLCD() { return lcd_; }
    LCDText *GetLCDText() { return lcdText_; }
    virtual void Connect(){};
    virtual void SetupDevice(){};
    std::map<std::string, Widget *> Widgets();
    std::string CFG_Key();
    LCDWrapper *GetWrapper() { return wrapper_; }

};
```

Is the problem that it subclasses other classes? I tried an experiment testing that theory, but it didn't produce this error.

Edit: Ok, so a couple of you guys pointed out I could be forward declaring Generic elsewhere without making it a template class. That's true. And when I make it a template, I get another error.

Property.h:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Generic' with no type

```
template <class T>
class Generic;

class Property : public CFG {
    Generic *visitor; // line 15
    bool is_valid;
    QScriptValue result;
    Json::Value *expression;
    public:
    Property(const Property &prop);
    Property(Generic *v, Json::Value *section, std::string name, Json::Value *defval);
    ~Property();
    bool Valid();
    int Eval();
    double P2N();
    int P2INT();
    std::string P2S();
    void SetValue(Json::Value val);
    Property operator=(Property prop);
};
```

Comment: What's line 25? Is it the `Q_OBJECT` line?

Comment: That's: class Generic: public QObject, public CFG, public virtual Evaluator {

Comment: Pardon the redundancy, but Generic is a fairly generic name, you might want to change the name to something more descriptive. And/or (but mostly and) place it in a namespace.

Comment: @GMan: True. I might change it to something like LCDGeneric. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but you **can't** subclass QObject with a template class.

[Here is more information about that.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120918081247/http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq15-academic.html)

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319876/weird-c-templating-issues) elsewhere on SO. Are you by any chance forward-declaring Generic somewhere, and not as a templated class?

**EDIT: 
In answer to your second error...**

@Steve Guidi has solved this problem in his comment elsewhere on this page. Now that you've consistently declared Generic as a templated class, line 15 of your Property.h is illegal because you're using Generic in an untemplated form.

You need to specify the specialization you're using on line 15, e.g.

```
template <class T>
class Generic;

class Property : public CFG {
    Generic<int> *visitor; // specialised use of Generic
    bool is_valid;
    QScriptValue result;
    Json::Value *expression;
    public:
    Property(const Property &prop);
    Property(Generic *v, Json::Value *section, std::string name, Json::Value *defval);
    ~Property();
    bool Valid();
    int Eval();
    double P2N();
    int P2INT();
    std::string P2S();
    void SetValue(Json::Value val);
    Property operator=(Property prop);
};
```

Comment: Ok, yeah that sort of just trickles down through-out my code in that case. Well, it's for a good reason, so I don't mind.

Comment: Trickles down meaning that I have to carry T through-out. :)

Answer (score 5):

might be that Generic is already defined somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, it's not that. Generic's in Generic.h only.

Comment: Wait, actually I have it elsewhere as a stub.

Comment: Does that stub say it's a template?

Comment: No, but when I added it, I get another error: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Generic' with no type. That's regarding this line: Generic *visitor;

Comment: @Scott: keep the stub declration with the template directives.  The compiler is now telling you that you are attempting to use `Generic` as a non-generic type (i.e. Generic* visitor) -- you need to specialize these instances too.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see whether the `#include` directive immediately above `Generic` has a closing `;` on its class definition.  I saw that error once, and that was the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are defining visitor of type Generic with no template param.

When you forward declared the class as Generic then at line 15 the compiler found the declaration. But when you changed the declaration with template then the class Generic is no longer found.

So, you should do something like:

```
template <class T>
class Generic;

class Property : public CFG {
    Generic<SomeType> *visitor; // line 15
```

or

```
template <class T>
class Generic;

template <class T>
class Property : public CFG {
    Generic<T> *visitor; // line 15
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Is that error generated by C++ compiler, or by Qt MOC? It might be that you can't actually apply Qt MOC on a template class.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried removing QObject, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issue that you are not defining the template class correctly (thus your error message), you cannot use a Q_OBJECT in a template class.
See http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq15-academic.html for details.